# How to get parent element from child instance in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save assignment into the database but I also want the name of the teacher who created that assignment and the title of the assignment. now assignment is getting saved but I dont know how to get the name of teacher and assignment title.
MODELS.PY:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    assignment_creator = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    assignment_details = models.TextField()
    assignment_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.assignment_title)



class Submissions(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    submission_file = models.FileField(null=False)
    submitted_to = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    submission_title = models.ForeignKey(
        Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    submission_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    t_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_Teacher = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.teacher_username)
```

this is my template where I am uploading the file and i am using these two hidden fields to get the name of assignment and teacher in string format.

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'assignment' %}" method="POST">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input type="text" name="ass_name" hidden value="{{assignment.assignment_title}}"
                                        id="">
                                    <input type="text" name="teacher_name" hidden
                                        value="{{assignment.assignment_creator}}" id="">
                                    <input required type="file" name="inputFile" id="" placeholder="upload">
                                    <button>Upload</button>

       

                                   )
```

I tried saving those two assignment name and teacher name in the database just like I saved the file but it isnt working because of the string. now I dont know how to fix this.

```
 uploaded_file = request.FILES['inputFile']
        ass_name = request.POST.get('ass_name')
        teacher_name = request.POST.get('teacher_name')
        print(uploaded_file)
        print(ass_name)

        student = Student.objects.get(student_username=request.user)
        std_instance = student





 document = Submissions.objects.create(submitted_by=std_instance,
                                              submission_file=uploaded_file,
                                              submission_status=True,submission_title =?, submitted_to=?

                                          )
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need hidden fields for this? All you need to know on the request is the assignment you're dealing with, right? You can pull everything else off the existing record.

Comment: I am using hidden input tags because I want to sent this assignment title and teacher title in same row as the file. you can see in this image https://imgur.com/lacRjh8

Comment: I dont know how to fetch rest of the record

Comment: But you're posting to an assignment endpoint, so you know all this info when you get the POST request, without having to send it back from the frontend.

Comment: what? I am sorry I don't get it I am only getting the file on backend not the person who created it. how can I know which teacher created that assignment? I have added the models.py in the question

Comment: But all you're doing on FE is setting those to values from the assignment record, so you have that data.

Comment: Wow Wow you got me, This is interesting let me try. I am very new to web dev so may be something is very easy but I might make it hard to look difficult haha

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assignments")
    ...

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

So whenever you want to access the assignment's teacher you can do `assignment.teacher` and you can access the username by doing `assignment.teacher.user.username`

Comment: Thanks but  I am getting this error now 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'teacher'

Comment: I used .teacher.user.username on that file which i am getting from template form.